# Setting up Raspberry Pi Pico Examples on Windows and CLion

Tags: pi-pico

I am attempting to just get the the Raspbery Pi Pico SDK examples working but I am running into an issue....

- System: windows 10
- IDE: CLion 2022.2.4
- CMAKE: 3.25.0-rc3
- Arm GNU Toolchain: 12.2.0
- Python: 3.11 (64-bit)

Following this guide, https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/pico/getting-started-with-pico.pdf, I have cloned the SDK and example repos, installed all the necessary toolchains, I believe everything is referenced in PATH correctly and I got as far as this:
[image]

But after "Build files have been written..." I get the following error repeated 170 ish times:

```
Compiler exited with error code 2: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe" @C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\response-file16444701572520888543 C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\compiler-file13210924529758865438 | @response-file16444701572520888543=/TP /DCFG_TUSB_DEBUG=1 /DCFG_TUSB_MCU=OPT_MCU_RP2040 /DCFG_TUSB_OS=OPT_OS_PICO /DLIB_PICO_BIT_OPS=1 /DLIB_PICO_BIT_OPS_PICO=1 /DLIB_PICO_BOOTSEL_VIA_DOUBLE_RESET=1 /DLIB_PICO_DIVIDER=1 /DLIB_PICO_DIVIDER_HARDWARE=1 /DLIB_PICO_DOUBLE=1 /DLIB_PICO_DOUBLE_PICO=1 /DLIB_PICO_FLOAT=1 /DLIB_PICO_FLOAT_PICO=1 /DLIB_PICO_INT64_OPS=1 /DLIB_PICO_INT64_OPS_PICO=1 /DLIB_PICO_MALLOC=1 /DLIB_PICO_MEM_OPS=1 /DLIB_PICO_MEM_OPS_PICO=1 /DLIB_PICO_PLATFORM=1 /DLIB_PICO_PRINTF=1 /DLIB_PICO_PRINTF_PICO=1 /DLIB_PICO_RUNTIME=1 /DLIB_PICO_STANDARD_LINK=1 /DLIB_PICO_STDIO=1 /DLIB_PICO_STDIO_UART=1 /DLIB_PICO_STDLIB=1 /DLIB_PICO_SYNC=1 /DLIB_PICO_SYNC_CORE=1 /DLIB_PICO_SYNC_CRITICAL_SECTION=1 /DLIB_PICO_SYNC_MUTEX=1 /DLIB_PICO_SYNC_SEM=1 /DLIB_PICO_TIME=1 /DLIB_PICO_UTIL=1 /DLIB_TINYUSB_BOARD=1 /DLIB_TINYUSB_HOST=1 "/DPICO_BOARD=\"pico\"" /DPICO_BUILD=1 "/DPICO_CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=\"Debug\"" /DPICO_COPY_TO_RAM=0 /DPICO_CXX_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS=0 /DPICO_NO_FLASH=0 /DPICO_NO_HARDWARE=0 /DPICO_ON_DEVICE=1 /DPICO_RP2040_USB_DEVICE_ENUMERATION_FIX=1 "/DPICO_TARGET_NAME=\"tinyusb_host_hid_controller\"" /DPICO_USE_BLOCKED_RAM=0 /DRP2040_USB_HOST_MODE=1 -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb -Og -Wall -Wno-format -Wno-unused-function -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-exceptions -fno-unwind-tables -fno-rtti -fno-use-cxa-atexit -std:c++17 /Be /Bd /EP
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.33.31630 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

all:
    @cd C:\Users\pico-examples\cmake-build-debug\usb\host\tinyusb_host_examples\hid_controller
    @set INCLUDE=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\ATLMFC\include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um
    @set LIB=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\ATLMFC\lib\x86;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\lib\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.19041.0\\um\x86
    @set LIBPATH=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\ATLMFC\lib\x86;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\lib\x86;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\lib\x86\store\references;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.19041.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.19041.0;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
    @set CL=
    @set _CL_=
    @set LINK=
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe @<< C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\compiler-file13210924529758865438
/TP /DCFG_TUSB_DEBUG=1 /DCFG_TUSB_MCU=OPT_MCU_RP2040 /DCFG_TUSB_OS=OPT_OS_PICO /DLIB_PICO_BIT_OPS=1 /DLIB_PICO_BIT_OPS_PICO=1 /DLIB_PICO_BOOTSEL_VIA_DOUBLE_RESET=1 /DLIB_PICO_DIVIDER=1 /DLIB_PICO_DIVIDER_HARDWARE=1 /DLIB_PICO_DOUBLE=1 /DLIB_PICO_DOUBLE_PICO=1 /DLIB_PICO_FLOAT=1 /DLIB_PICO_FLOAT_PICO=1 /DLIB_PICO_INT64_OPS=1 /DLIB_PICO_INT64_OPS_PICO=1 /DLIB_PICO_MALLOC=1 /DLIB_PICO_MEM_OPS=1 /DLIB_PICO_MEM_OPS_PICO=1 /DLIB_PICO_PLATFORM=1 /DLIB_PICO_PRINTF=1 /DLIB_PICO_PRINTF_PICO=1 /DLIB_PICO_RUNTIME=1 /DLIB_PICO_STANDARD_LINK=1 /DLIB_PICO_STDIO=1 /DLIB_PICO_STDIO_UART=1 /DLIB_PICO_STDLIB=1 /DLIB_PICO_SYNC=1 /DLIB_PICO_SYNC_CORE=1 /DLIB_PICO_SYNC_CRITICAL_SECTION=1 /DLIB_PICO_SYNC_MUTEX=1 /DLIB_PICO_SYNC_SEM=1 /DLIB_PICO_TIME=1 /DLIB_PICO_UTIL=1 /DLIB_TINYUSB_BOARD=1 /DLIB_TINYUSB_HOST=1 "/DPICO_BOARD=\"pico\"" /DPICO_BUILD=1 "/DPICO_CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=\"Debug\"" /DPICO_COPY_TO_RAM=0 /DPICO_CXX_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS=0 /DPICO_NO_FLASH=0 /DPICO_NO_HARDWARE=0 /DPICO_ON_DEVICE=1 /DPICO_RP2040_USB_DEVICE_ENUMERATION_FIX=1 "/DPICO_TARGET_NAME=\"tinyusb_host_hid_controller\"" /DPICO_USE_BLOCKED_RAM=0 /DRP2040_USB_HOST_MODE=1 -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb -Og -Wall -Wno-format -Wno-unused-function -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-exceptions -fno-unwind-tables -fno-rtti -fno-use-cxa-atexit -std:c++17 /Be /Bd /EP<<

cl /TP /DCFG_TUSB_DEBUG=1 /DCFG_TUSB_MCU=OPT_MCU_RP2040 /DCFG_TUSB_OS=OPT_OS_PICO /DLIB_PICO_BIT_OPS=1 /DLIB_PICO_BIT_OPS_PICO=1 /DLIB_PICO_BOOTSEL_VIA_DOUBLE_RESET=1 /DLIB_PICO_DIVIDER=1 /DLIB_PICO_DIVIDER_HARDWARE=1 /DLIB_PICO_DOUBLE=1 /DLIB_PICO_DOUBLE_PICO=1 /DLIB_PICO_FLOAT=1 /DLIB_PICO_FLOAT_PICO=1 /DLIB_PICO_INT64_OPS=1 /DLIB_PICO_INT64_OPS_PICO=1 /DLIB_PICO_MALLOC=1 /DLIB_PICO_MEM_OPS=1 /DLIB_PICO_MEM_OPS_PICO=1 /DLIB_PICO_PLATFORM=1 /DLIB_PICO_PRINTF=1 /DLIB_PICO_PRINTF_PICO=1 /DLIB_PICO_RUNTIME=1 /DLIB_PICO_STANDARD_LINK=1 /DLIB_PICO_STDIO=1 /DLIB_PICO_STDIO_UART=1 /DLIB_PICO_STDLIB=1 /DLIB_PICO_SYNC=1 /DLIB_PICO_SYNC_CORE=1 /DLIB_PICO_SYNC_CRITICAL_SECTION=1 /DLIB_PICO_SYNC_MUTEX=1 /DLIB_PICO_SYNC_SEM=1 /DLIB_PICO_TIME=1 /DLIB_PICO_UTIL=1 /DLIB_TINYUSB_BOARD=1 /DLIB_TINYUSB_HOST=1 "/DPICO_BOARD=\"pico\"" /DPICO_BUILD=1 "/DPICO_CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=\"Debug\"" /DPICO_COPY_TO_RAM=0 /DPICO_CXX_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS=0 /DPICO_NO_FLASH=0 /DPICO_NO_HARDWARE=0 /DPICO_ON_DEVICE=1 /DPICO_RP2040_USB_DEVICE_ENUMERATION_FIX=1 "/DPICO_TARGET_NAME=\"tinyusb_host_hid_controller\"" /DPICO_USE_BLOCKED_RAM=0 /DRP2040_USB_HOST_MODE=1 -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb -Og -Wall -Wno-format -Wno-unused-function -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-exceptions -fno-unwind-tables -fno-rtti -fno-use-cxa-atexit -std:c++17 /Be /Bd /EP
cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'Og' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-format'
```

[Failed to reload]

Any help would be appreciated, I am new to this so forgive me if I am ommitting key information.

Here are some potentially helpful screenshots of CLion settings:
[image]

[image]